# Partially Bold Text in an HTML select

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if this is even possible, but I have a case where I'd like to bold **part** (not all) of the text within an option of an HTML select tag.

I tried using b tags, as well as strong tags, with no luck (on Chrome). CSS might work, but since it works at the element level, I'm not sure how to go about it that way.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The pseudo-elements `:first-letter` and `:first-line` can give you some control of this, but it's probably not as much fine-tuning as you'd like.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No; it's not possible.

Instead, you can make a fake dropdown list using Javascript.

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, is there another, easier solution, look at Pritesh answer.

Answer (score 10):

since chrome doesn't allow bold font on option tag . you can use text-shadow property like

text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px black;

it will give same appearance of bold and work on all the browsers

Comment: Why is this so low-voted? It solved my problem. It seems "people continue in a rush nowadays".

Comment: You can also use 'text-shadow: 1px 1px black;'

Comment: It's presumably low-voted becaue it's wrong - (a) it doesn't bold only part of the text, as the OP requested, and (b) only `color`, i think, is cross-browser.

Comment: @EML Even color is not cross-browser. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#styling_with_css: "In Firefox, only color and background-color can be set, however in Chrome and Safari it's not possible to set any properties."

Answer (score 8):

No, this is not possible. You have two options here:

1) Use the `<optgroup>` to create a descriptive header for what you're doing (unlikely this will help).

2) Simulate a drop-down menu by using JavaScript. I'm not sure, but I think jQuery UI might have a drop-down menu script.

Answer (score 1):

I think its too late but this thing worked for me.
Apply the property 'font-weight: bolder' to the option tag to make text within it bold without using any html tags.

```
<option value="optionValue" class="bold-option">
.bold-option{font-weight: bolder;}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Firefox. I think this is still pretty browser-specific though.

Comment: The request was to bold only partial text.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution:

```
<select>
  <option>Simple</option>
  <option class='bolden'>Bold</option>
  <option>Simple</option>
</select>
<style>
  .bolden{font-family:"Arial Black"}
</style>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/hnzhbz69/

Comment: He people! Pay attention! The problem requested was how to bold only part of the text!

Comment: This answer assumes that font ships with the user's OS, which it may not.

Comment: I tried using this with mdboostrap but it didn't howr for me

Answer (score 0):

using CSS yes it's possible

```css
   option[value='4']{
    font-weight:bold;
}
/*
Here you can used also :nth of the options that you need to apply specific css like
option:nth-child(1), option:nth-child(4) {
    font-weight:bold;
}
*/
```

```html
<select>
<option value='1'>first</option>
<option value='2'>Second</option>
<option value='3'>Third</option>
<option value='4'>Fourth</option>
<option value='5'>Fifth</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Contradicts the question asking that only part of the text of one option be bold. This will make *all* of the text of one option be bold

Answer (score -1):

Bold a nth option in select.

There is no way to do this in css. If still differentiation between options is required, use color, and background.

```
.diff-option {
   color : grey;
}
.other-options{
   color:white
   background: ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well, you can use the `<strong>` or `<b>` in firefox, but it won't work in Chrome or in IE (not cheked any other)

Comment: Not even MDN suggests that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option - You should provide reference and name that feature. If none exists, this is pretty fragile.

Answer (score -6):

Try to wrap the text with `<span id="wrap">Some text</span>` in css do this 
`#wrap {font-weight: bold}`

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. I just tested it, doesn't work.

Comment: You can't put tags in `<option>` elements.

Comment: You could try to add a style to option element itself, but I doubt that will help. :)

Comment: Actually, I made an aqua-button style dropdown with only CSS by adding styles to the `select` and `option` elements.