# Making <option> text bold

Tags: html, css, select, styling

I am trying to make a  text bold that is outputted by php.

Tried `<b>`, `<strong>` and CSS but it didnt work.

My php:

```
function generateWeekNumbers() { //Generate a list with week numbers for dropdown
    $weekCount = 53;
    $currentWeek = getWeekNumber();
    for($i=1;$i<$weekCount;$i++)
    {
        if ($i == $currentWeek) {
            echo '<option><span class="week">Week '.$i.'</span></option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option>Week '.$i.'</option>';
        }
    }
}
```

My css on the actual page:

```
.week {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Also tried:

```
echo '<option><b>Week '.$i.'</b></option>';
```

Hope someone can help.

Comment: You cannot style `<option>`s like that. Nothing to do with php. It is up to individual user agents to render it in a specific way. You cannot control this without a custom `select`.

Comment: It *can't* be done cross-browser...

Comment: Please check whether its entering if condition or not. I guess its not entering if. Because it should work in some of the browsers.

Comment: If you really need this, you will have to replace the select with a custom element for it to be cross browser. Although not recommended

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951623/partially-bold-text-in-an-html-select

Comment: @PeeHaa is right, you can try http://jsfiddle.net/t3n6U/1/ -- in Firefox it will work, but not in IE or Chrome.

Comment: @user2911924: Here you want to make all options "bold", or only selected one?

Answer (score 3):

You can not style option tag by using pure CSS.

You should have a look at this library.

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

Answer (score 3):

You can set a font for options bold by using the `font-weight: bold`on the `<select>`tag.

For example:

```
<select>
    <option>Hallo</option>
</select>
```

And the CSS:

```
select{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

This will change the options to bold text.