# Jquery selectbox strong tag help required

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Jquery NiceSelect Plugin for my select boxes but I want a little change in it i.e. 
I want to use the strong or b tag in options but this plugin automatically converts html into

```
<label class="nice_label">Some Text Etc</label>
```

and into this

```
<p class="top">Some Text Etc</p>
```

but I want to exclude the conversion of strong tag or bold tag so that it would work like this

```
<label class="nice_label">Some Text <strong>Etc</strong></label>
```

Here is my JS

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.niceselect = function()
    {

        return this.each(function(index,value)
        {
            /*SET VARIABLES
            ============================*/
            var name = $(this).attr('name')
            var select = $(this);
            var num = index;
            var multi = false;
            var multix = '';
            var type= 'radio';
            var required = '';
            var classes = '';
            var selected = '';
            var placeholder = 'Select';

            if(select.attr('multiple') !== undefined)
            {
                multi = true;
                multix = '[]';
                type= 'checkbox';
            }       

            if($(this).attr('class') !== undefined)
            {
                var classes = $(this).attr('class');
            }

            if(select.find('[value="placeholder"]').length > 0)
            {
                placeholder = select.find('[value="placeholder"]').html();
            }

            if(typeof( select.attr('required') ) != 'undefined')
            {
                required = 'required';
            }

            /*WRAP SELECT IN DIV
            -------------------------*/
            select.wrap('<div class="select_style '+classes+'"/>');
            $('<span class="selectcon">&nbsp;</span>').insertBefore(select);


            /*CREATE PLACEHOLDER + OPTION BOX
            --------------------------------------------*/
            $('<div class="niceselect '+name+'" data-multi="'+multi+'"><p class="top">'+placeholder+'</p><div class="value_wrapper"></div></div>').insertBefore(this)           


            /*CREATE OPTGROUP BOXES
            --------------------------------------------*/

            if(select.find('optgroup').length > 0)
            {
                select.find('optgroup').each(function(key, opt){
                    select.siblings('.niceselect').children('.value_wrapper').append('<div class="opt opt'+key+'"><span class="optTitle">'+$(opt).attr('label')+'</span></div>')

                        $(opt).find('option').each(function(index,value){


                            var val;
                            if($(this).val() == '')
                            { 

                                 val = $(this).html();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                 val = $(this).val();
                            }

                            var txt = $(this).html();


                            selected = '';
                            if(typeof( $(this).attr('selected') ) != 'undefined')
                            {
                                selected = 'checked';
                                select.siblings('.niceselect').find('p.top').html(txt)
                            }


                            select.siblings('.niceselect').find('.opt'+key).append('<div class="values"><input type="'+type+'"  '+required+' '+selected+' style=" pointer-events: none;" name="'+name+multix+'" value="'+val+'" data-text="'+txt+'" id="'+index+name+index+'" /> <label class="nice_label" >'+txt+'</label></div>')

                        })
                    })


            }
            /*CREATE GENERAL OPTION FIELDS*/
            else
            {
                select.find('option').each(function(index,value){

                        var $this = $(this);
                        var val;
                        if($(this).val() == '')
                        { 

                             val = $(this).html();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                             val = $(this).val();
                        }

                        var txt = $(this).html();
                        selected = '';
                        if(typeof( $(this).attr('selected') ) != 'undefined')
                        {
                            selected = 'checked';
                            select.siblings('.niceselect').find('p.top').html(txt)
                        }


                        select.siblings('.niceselect').children('.value_wrapper').append('<div class="values"><input type="'+type+'" '+required+' '+selected+' style=" pointer-events: none;" name="'+name+multix+'" value="'+val+'" data-text="'+txt+'" id="'+index+name+index+'" /> <label class="nice_label" >'+txt+'</label></div>')

                    })

            }

            select.remove()
            select.attr('name','blobla')



            /*BIND CLICK FUNCTIONS (hide / show menu)
            ===========================================*/
            $('body').on('click',function()
            {
                $('.niceselect .value_wrapper').hide();

                $('.select_style').removeClass('active')
            })

            $('body').on('click','.niceselect',function(e)
            {
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                if($(this).parent().hasClass('active'))
                {
                    $(this).find('.value_wrapper').hide();
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
                    console.log('here')
                }
                else
                {
                    //$('.niceselect .value_wrapper').hide();
                    $(this).children('.value_wrapper').show()
                    $(this).parent().addClass('active')
                }
            })


            /*BIND CLICK FUNCTIONS (check values / update visual)
            =====================================================*/         

            $('body').on('click','.niceselect .value_wrapper .values',function(e){
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                var checkBoxes = $(this).find('input');

                var par = $(this).parent().parent();
                if(par.attr('data-multi') == 'true')
                {


                     if($(this).hasClass('active'))
                     {
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                     }


                }
                else
                {
                     $(this).parent().parent().find('input[checked]').removeAttr('checked')
                     $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');

                     if($(this).hasClass('active'))
                     {
                        $(this).removeClass('active');
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                     }

                     $('.niceselect .value_wrapper').hide();
                     $('.select_style').removeClass('active')

                }


                 checkBoxes.prop("checked", !checkBoxes.prop("checked"));

                 checkBoxes.trigger('change')
            })
            $('body').on('click','.niceselect .value_wrapper .values label',function(e){e.preventDefault()})
            $('body').on('change','.niceselect .values input',function(e){

                var par = $(this).closest('.niceselect')
                if(par.attr('data-multi') == 'true')
                {
                    var number = par.find('input:checked').length;

                    par.find('p.top').html(number + ' Selected')                
                }
                else
                {
                    par.find('p.top').html($(this).attr('data-text'))
                }
            })




            /*SEARCH OPTIONS IN SELECT BOX
            ----------------------------------------*/


        var string = '';
        $('body').on('keypress',function(e){

            if($('.value_wrapper').is(':visible'))
            {
                var clearString;
                $('.value_wrapper .highlight').removeClass('highlight')

                clearInterval(clearString)
                string = string+String.fromCharCode(e.which);

                if(string.length == 1)
                {
                    string = string.toUpperCase();
                }           

                var thing = $('.value_wrapper:visible').find('label:contains('+string+')').first();


                $(thing).parent().addClass('highlight')
                if($('.value_wrapper:visible').find('.highlight').length > 0)
                {
                    $('.value_wrapper:visible').stop().scrollTop($('.value_wrapper:visible').scrollTop() + $('.highlight').position().top)
                }
                clearString = setTimeout(function(){string = ''},500);
            }



        })




        })          
    }

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Can you share more HTML, or a working example on jsfiddle.net please?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to do this:

```
/*CREATE GENERAL OPTION FIELDS*/
        else
        {
            select.find('option').each(function(index,value){

                    var $this = $(this);
                    var val;
                    if($(this).val() == '')
                    { 

                         val = $(this).html();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         val = $(this).val();
                    }

                    var txt = $(this).html();
                    selected = '';
                    if(typeof( $(this).attr('selected') ) != 'undefined')
                    {
                        selected = 'checked';
                        select.siblings('.niceselect').find('p.top').html(txt)
                    }
                   select.siblings('.niceselect').children('.value_wrapper').append('<div class="values"><input type="'+type+'" '+required+' '+selected+' style=" pointer-events: none;" name="'+name+multix+'" value="'+val+'" data-text="'+txt+'" id="'+index+name+index+'" /> <label class="nice_label" ><b>'+txt+'</b></label></div>')

                })

        }

        select.remove()
        select.attr('name','blobla')
```

Notice that I only have changed this line:

```
                    select.siblings('.niceselect').children('.value_wrapper').append('<div class="values"><input type="'+type+'" '+required+' '+selected+' style=" pointer-events: none;" name="'+name+multix+'" value="'+val+'" data-text="'+txt+'" id="'+index+name+index+'" /> <label class="nice_label" ><b>'+txt+'</b></label></div>')
```

Copy & paste this part of the code and test it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggesstion but what i acutally want is, if i write this option tag in my html e.g. ``<option>Some text <strong>here</strong></option>`` i want the inner html of this option tag remain same rather then it removes the strong tag and place only text in label and p tag for you clearance instead of this `<label class="nice_label" >'Some Text Here'</label></div>` i want the html to print out which keep my CSS work for strong tag

Comment: That it's not possible. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951623/partially-bold-text-in-an-html-select